# Filter from a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to create a dropdown list that filters multiple items based on the `STATUT` variable

[image]

```
TOUS   = 0 
ENCORE = 1
ANNULE = 8
FAIT   = 9
```

I show you the inferface

```
export interface TransferResponse extends ApiResponse {
    PRE: Transfer[];
}

export interface Transfer {
    DEPO: number;
    CLER: string;
    INTITULE1: string;
    PHONE: string;
    PREPTF: {
        LABEL: string;
        TYPE: string;
        QUANTITE: number;
        STATUT: number; /* Variable  to filter */ 
        NUM: number;
        ISIN: string;
        STATUT_LIB: string;
        REF_RBC: string;
    }[];
}
```

The template

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="currentAgency">
   <div class="card-body">
      <form #formulaire="ngForm" >
         <div class=" row mb-4 align-items-end ">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="mb-2">
                  <h5>Sélectionnez un item </h5>
                  <select id="item-select" class="form-select form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatut" (change)="onChangeStatut($event)">
                  <option selected disabled value="">Sélectionnez un item</option>
                  <option [value]="''">TOUS</option>
                  <option [value]="'1'">ENCODE </option>
                  <option [value]="'8'">ANNULE</option>
                  <option [value]="'9'">FAIT</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
         <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
               <!-- DEPO -->
               <th>DEPO</th>
               <!-- STATUT  -->
               <th>STATUT</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let transfer of transferResponse.PRE">
               <ng-container *ngFor="let preptf of transfer.PREPTF">
                  <tr>
                     <td class="text-start">
                        <a class="link-primary" role="button">
                        {{ transfer.DEPO  }} 
                        </a>
                     </td>
                     <ng-container *ngIf="preptf.STATUT === 1">
                        <td class="text-center">{{preptf.STATUT_LIB}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center py-1">
                           <!-- Annuler -->
                           <button (click)="onDeletePreptf(preptf)" class="btn btn-success outline btn-xs"> Annuler</button>
                        </td>
                     </ng-container>
                     <ng-container *ngIf="preptf.STATUT === 8">
                        <td class="text-center">{{preptf.STATUT_LIB}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center py-1">
                        </td>
                     </ng-container>
                     <ng-container *ngIf="preptf.STATUT === 9">
                        <td class="text-center">{{preptf.STATUT_LIB}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center py-1"></td>
                     </ng-container>
                  </tr>
               </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I select an item, for example `FAIT` (Statut=9)

[image]

After selecting an item, the filter does not run. I share you some consoles.log.

[image]

How can I make my filter work?

component

```
export class OverviewTransfersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();

   currentAgency: any;
   transferResponse: TransferResponse;
   account: string;

   selectedStatut;

   filteredTransfers: Transfer[] = [];

   constructor(
      private service: OverviewTransfersService,
      private store: Store,
      private modalService: BsModalService,
      private router: Router


   ) {
      this.account = '';
      this.selectedStatut = ''; // initialization of the selectStatus variable
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.currentAgency = this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency);
      if (this.currentAgency) {
         this.overviewTransfers(this.account);
      }
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unsubscribe$.next();
      this.unsubscribe$.complete();
   }

   overviewTransfers(account: string): void {
      this.service.overviewTransfers(account).pipe(
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(res => {
         if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.transferResponse = res as TransferResponse;
            console.log("data => ", this.transferResponse);
         }
      });
   }

   filterByStatut(): void {
      console.log("Before filter :", this.transferResponse.PRE);
      if (this.transferResponse && this.transferResponse.PRE && this.selectedStatut) {
         this.filteredTransfers = this.transferResponse.PRE.filter((transfer) =>
            transfer.PREPTF.some((preptf) => preptf.STATUT === this.selectedStatut)
         );
      } else {
         this.filteredTransfers = this.transferResponse.PRE || [];
      }
      console.log("After filter :", this.filteredTransfers);
   }

   onChangeStatut(event: any) {
      this.selectedStatut = event.target.value;
      console.log("Selected value:", this.selectedStatut);
      this.filterByStatut();
   }
}
```